# Nexus 7 installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I'm stuck between steps 2 and 3, I get to a Welcome screen, select language and an arrow to setup wifi. no option is available to enable debugging. any suggestions?

Comment: What instructions are you following?

Comment: from:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Comment: **Did you read 'Step 3' - "Enable USB debugging on the device"?** *ie. *tap on build number 7 times*

Comment: Look under 'Developer Options' in 'Settings'

Comment: apparently, i didn't finish the "setup" since the previous steps reset my tablet. after getting to the "build number" and tapping it 7xs it displayed a bubble "you are now a developer".

Comment: now i'm not too sure which command to run for step 4, there seems to be a lot and i don't want to mess this up.

Comment: Either **`phablet-flash ubuntu-system --channel devel --no-backup`** (for R/O image install) **OR** **`phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b`** (for older 'standard' install). *Where 'image' is the newer, faster way; and 'standard' is deprecated except for die-hard traditionalist (like me).*

Comment: i ran "phablet-flash ubuntu-system --channel devel --no-backup", message: ROM may flash stock recovery on boot. Fix? THIS CAN NOT BE UNDONE." (7) "No", "Yes - Disable recovery flash.", (3) "No", "+++++ Go Back +++++". now what?

Comment: since no other replys were made i selected "Yes - Disable recovery flash." and it booted fine, but now i have a new problem with wifi - "wifi setting" is blank there is no option to set or setup a new connection. how do would i manually set this up if this area is blank?

Comment: Pull down the top-right corner. (If necessary) slide to left or right, then select 'Network' ..

Comment: i broadcasted on my SSID, connected, then turn it back off.

Comment: @david6 Please write up your comments in the form of an answer as it appears that the OP has now been successful in installing Ubuntu on the Nexus 7. Thank you!

Comment: Valid comment, but only for my initial posting (on Debugging Mode). **REMAINDER of thread is DEFUNCT,** since **phablet-flash** has been replaced by **ubuntu-device-flash**.